# Run a JobService Constantly in Android-Even App is killed

Tags: android, firebase, service, background

I am just newbie to android,please help a little. i am trying to use **JobService** or **com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobService** in my android application but as far as i studied i see that the JOB SERVICE runs on Main Thread and as long as application is running either in background or forground it keep doing its schedule work.

But the issue is i want to do Get users location lets say after every 30 minutes even if the application is removed from application tray. i am confused in following points

1. If i run a sticky service it does not give me scheduling
2. If i use Job Service it gives scheduling but terminates as application is
   closed.

**Is there any way to run a service which run even after application is killed and do schedule tasks as well?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `AlarmManager` [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) 
Create Your Server class :

```
public class MService extends IntentService {
    public MyTestService() {
       super("MService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
       // Your firebase task
    }
}
```

then your broadcast

```
public class MReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent in = new Intent(context, MService.class);
    context.startService(in);
  }
}
```

finally

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MReceiver.class);
final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked!!!! but i was wondering my same code was not doing any scheduling on huawei p9lite(API 24) and same code done scheduling on Qmobile S5(API 21). What could be the possible reason?

Comment: it's about background services policy for the api 23+ to protect users from services that can drain your batteries and network. please check it as solved :)